# Missing contentDescription attribute on image in android XML

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Why do i get this warning in ImageView in android?

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml

Comment: That's a lint warning that you are missing this attribute  `android:src="@drawable/mydrawable"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the attribute "android:contentDescription" in your ImageView.

Example :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription" />
```

This warning is thrown to be sure that your ImageView describes his content by a brief text.