# No orientation specified error message

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add an image 
below is the xml code which has buttonpayicon as the image

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonplayicon" />
```

I have added below snippet in strings.xml

```
 <string name="imageView1">Enter a message</string>
```

When I run the project I get below error message

```
Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_alignParentBottom    activity_main.xml   /FirstAppPradnnya/res/layout    line 25 Android Lint Problem
[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image   activity_main.xml   /FirstAppPradnnya/res/layout    line 28 Android Lint Problem
Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"    activity_main.xml   /FirstAppPradnnya/res/layout    line 1  Android Lint Problem
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: post complete xml file

Comment: Please post the **complete** `activity_main.xml` layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following to your `layout xml` file as

1 . `layout_alignParentBottom` is for `RelativeLayout` not for `LinearLayout`.
So remove this from your layout file.

2 . Add `android:orientation="vertical"` under tag as

```
    <LinearLayout 
    //your tags
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

3 . And for `content Description`,

this link ['Missing contentDescription attribute on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml) will help you.

And for Others please post `activity_main.xml` file.