# imageviews error

Tags: android

Missing contentDescription attribute on image  Non-textual widgets like ImageViews and ImageButtons should use the contentDescription attribute to specify a textual description of the widget such that screen readers and other accessibility tools can adequately describe the user interface.  Note that elements in application screens that are purely decorative and do not provide any content or enable a user action should not have accessibility content descriptions. In this case, just suppress the lint warning with tools, ignore"ContentDescription" attribute.  Note that for text fields, you should not set both the hint and the contentDescription attributes since the hint will never be shown. Just set the hint. See

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

add contentDescription="some text" in layout in imageview /imagebutton
dont put hint in these views.
contentDescription and hint should not be in same view 
check xml of layout .