# Image View showing warning as unknown attribute android:contentDescription in AS 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, androidx

When I updated my Android studio from 3.3 to 3.4.1, I was facing some interesting warning in my ImageView tag like: `android:contentDescription attribute is unknown`. How I can resolve this warning? Or is it a bug of new Android Studio 3.4.1?

Comment: Obviously, that is not a bug. You can check this here which is properly explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731353/9162370

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Missing contentDescription attribute on image' in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730673/missing-contentdescription-attribute-on-image-in-xml)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it's not duplicate. Also same warning for "android: padding". My question is specific, I got warning as "unknown attribute android:contentDescription" and second same warning for padding "unknown attribute android:padding".

Comment: I'm experiencing the same warning: `Unknown attribute android:contentDescription` on AS Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2.

I'm also getting a similar warning for scaleType attribute: `Unknown attribute android:scaleType`.

Comment: It looks related to a compileSdkVersion 33 issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622172/unknown-attribute-warning-in-xml and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235792434